# PHP page not redrawing after redirect to new received from get_file_contents

Tags: php, html

my code:-

```
$host = "https://example.org/get.php?";
$newurl = file_get_contents($url);
$newurl = substr($newurl,stripos($newurl,"who"));
$newurl = substr($newurl,0,stripos($newurl,"</"));
// newurl string starts with "who" and ends with "</"
//var_dump($host.$newurl)."<br>";  //shows correct request string
header("Location: " . $host.$newurl);
exit();
```

new window displays the correct url request in the address bar but isn't redrawn
page source is blank except a single "1" char.
on pressing the resubmit button the page is drawn correctly.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Stve

Comment: The `$url` variable in `file_get_contents($url)` is not defined?

Comment: If you output something before `header`, then you invalidate headers

Comment: Please edit your question and post more of your file.  It is most likely that you have output something.  The header only works if no html has been output!!!

Comment: The $url is correct! please see below for more analysis

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `file_get_contents($url);` to `$host` because it's not correct source url

Comment: I have investigated to out from the php script and fount that it did not output directly to the browser but I added new code

Comment: flush();
//header("Location: " . $host.$newurl);
exit();

Comment: That yielded :-<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><title>https://example.org/get.php?who=XYZ&amp;fun=xyz&amp;ucn=111&amp;item=265&amp;chk=QT93</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://content-accessible/viewsource.css"></head><body id="viewsource" class="wrap highlight" style="tab-size: 4"><pre id="line1"><span></span></pre></body></html>

Comment: How do I stop all output before the header("Location: " . $host.$newurl); statement??

Comment: @Rohit Gupta - hi I too started on the Amstrad with Turbo Pascal. In the above code the $url was to a local java server via http:127.0.0.1:port ... it was recieved correctly and gave the correct result.

Comment: I checked all output statements and no html is out put. I have disabled buffering via fastcgi_buffering off: in nginx.conf and added  header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
ob_end_flush(); at start of php file and before the header("Location: " . $host.$newurl);
exit(); statements.

Comment: it also includes clearstatcache(); to clear the cache. It displays the correct newurl but does refresh!!!! WHY????

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - If other people have a similar problem I would urge them to check that what they think is being offered up to file_get_contents($url) and to header("Location: $host$newurl"); is correct.  Not is my case.

Is this case the PHP was interfacing with my java server which it did in two ways the file_get_contents($url); updated the database and returned a new url. Then the header("Location: $host$newurl"); showed the updated page.

Secondly - make sure the server is doing what you expect. In this case the server had closed the socket after the file_get_contents($url); so could not respond to the header("Location: $host$newurl");

Even old hands fall into the trap of believing their code is correct!

Thanks all for you reponses.

Steve